# How to: Add an icon for my WPF app in the notification area of my win 7 taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, notifications, tray

I am working on a new WPF application.. and I need to show a notification area icon for it..

in windows forms I used to use notifyicon class but that is not supported in WPF...

so can you help me do that...

thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement your own control. [Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_notifyicon.aspx) a control I used a while ago.

Comment: I just want to show an icon in an notification area, with out any notifications..

Comment: I hope you can give simple code that can i put in window_load function.. to add that button... thanks..